Not able to install APK on Android as version already exists (ADB not a viable solution)
I am trying to update an app via installing an APK, however in testing I saw that even when the previous version of the app was uninstalled, the latest version could not be installed. The app is built using Flutter, but I am unsure if that is relevant.
I used ADB and saw that the phone detects a version of the package still installed, so using ADB, I uninstalled the "ghost" app and then it installs properly, via both ADB and running the APK. Is there a way to solve this without using ADB and without a factory reset, as this would not be a viable solution when this update is distributed outside testing, as I cannot expect a large body of users to do the same. Other than ADB, I have also cleared the cache of the package manager, deleted the package in the file manager, and reset app preferences.
